# unable to set vector drawable on KITKAT

Tags: android

I am using a vector drawable,it causes an exception on API 19

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
```

in my gradle i have added `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in the `defaultConfig`.

this is the code that doesn't work with this version:

```
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.yarolegovich.lovelydialog.R.id.ld_icon);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_my_location_black_24dp);
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure u have gradle version 2.0 or above
 if not then add this along with your current gradle configs to `build.gradle`

```
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     generatedDensities = []  
  }  

  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
 }
```

and use `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"` in your `imageView`

Answer (score 1):

[VectorDrawables](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html)

Support Library 23.2 or higher provides full support to Vector Drawables and Animated Vector Drawables on devices running Android 5.0 (API level 21) or lower.But unfortunately vector drawables can only be used with Imageview that too with `android:srcCompact` below Api 21 not the other way around like as a button background or anything ,

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
yourImageView.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.your_vector_drawable_here, null));
```

Comment: Whats your `com.android.tools.build:gradle` version ?

Comment: com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2 @Borislav Kamenov

Answer (score 0):

Use 
defaultConfig {
         ..
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

in build.gradle file (app module) and

app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_check"

in ImageView..